# Can I access variables of other extension's JavaScript?

Tags: firefox

I am building an overlay extension for an existing extension. How can I use the objects declared in that extension's JavaScript? Will the namespace of my JavaScript restrict me?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Just found that by adding the below code and adding the reference to the chrome path of the javascript of the extension, I could access its method's and properties.